# how to include associated models in the JSON result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these 3 models, Topic and Post are in a many-to-many-through relationship.

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_topic
  has_many :posts, through: :posts_topics

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 3..26 }, uniqueness: true
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_topic
  has_many :topics, through: :post_topic

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 3..255 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { in: 3..1400 }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :topics, allow_destroy: true
end

class PostTopic < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "posts_topics"
  belongs_to :post 
  belongs_to :topic 
end
```

When I fetch the posts, I want the JSON object to have topics included as well, something like this:

```
{
   title: ...,
   body: ...,
   topics: [ ... ]
}
```

I have used the includes method to include the association, but when I used httpie to test the result, the posts returned don't contain the associated records.

```
def index 
    @posts = Post.includes(:topics).all 

    json_response(@posts)
end
```

Here's the httpie result:

```
[
    {
        "body": "bar",
        "created_at": "2017-04-13T00:29:51.506Z",
        "id": 1,
        "title": "foo",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-13T00:29:51.506Z"
    },
    {
        "body": "bar",
        "created_at": "2017-04-13T21:20:21.854Z",
        "id": 2,
        "title": "foo",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-13T21:20:21.854Z"
    },
    {
        "body": "bar",
        "created_at": "2017-04-13T21:22:02.979Z",
        "id": 3,
        "title": "foo",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-13T21:22:02.979Z"
    }
]
```

Isn't the include method supposed to put the associated records inside the return object??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `include` puts the associated records, but you're using it in the wrong place, try this:

```
def index 
  @posts = Post.all 
  json_response(@posts.as_json(include: :topics))
end
```

Check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html) for more information.